# pcre regex to capture this string

Tags: php, pcre

I'm trying to capture the parts of a string to have resulting data like this:

```
name#foo|bar:str1,str2,str3
anothername#bar|zar
```

where the input string is in the form: `name#foo|bar:str1,str2,str3,anothername#bar|zar`

The problem is the separation of the `anothername` from the preceding args as it still uses a comma to separate it.

I've tried with a lookahead and also a subpattern with no luck!

```
preg_match_all('/([^,]+#.+(?:[^,]+#)?)/', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: [`([^,]+?#.*?(?=,[^,]+?#|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/aN9sQ4/1)

Answer (score 1):

This one is about [4 times faster](https://regex101.com/r/d4f392/1).

```
[^,#]++#(?:[^,#]++(?:,[^,#]++)*)(?=,|$)
```